# Soldering iron tip size for through hole components

Tags: soldering

I want to solder through hole components on a 2.54mm pitch perforated board. I have a 30W soldering iron with a 2mm wide chisel tip.
Is my tip too big for the job, should i buy a new one?
Best regards,
Explyy

Comment: I recommend you watch the EEVBlog introductionary videos about soldering.

Comment: What PlasmaHH says and I would consider 2mm too small but before buying a new one, just try it and see how far you get.

Comment: The tip should be about the same size as the joint being soldered.

Comment: Much more important than the tip would probably be that you have high thermal capacity iron on a temperature controlled soldering station.

Comment: 2mm is fine. I used to use a 1.6mm but now I actually prefer a 4mm if there is space. Heats up better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say that 2mm is probably a little on the large side but a lot if it is down to personal opinion.

However there are some important things to consider when choosing the tip size.

- How much heat will the component need to solder to the board, a smaller tip will not be able to heat large areas of metal as effectively
- What size area will you be soldering. In your case 2.54mm between pads is plenty of space for a large tip.

I generally find the standard tip most irons come with okay for pretty much anything.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! :) I was a bit worried about solder bridges between 2 pads but, as you said, the tip should be ok for stripboard soldering.

Comment: Exactly personal opinion. I would find it a little on the small side.

Answer (score 0):

Hakko [recommends](https://www.hakko.com/english/tip_selection/selection_1.html) the tip to be the same size as the pad. [This guy](https://www.instructables.com/id/Tips-for-choosing-the-correct-soldering-iron-tip/) says it should be 60 % of the pad size. Dave of EEVblog [seems to be using](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fYz5nIHH0iY) the tip roughly the same size as the pad.

From the general physics logic, I would recommend having as wide tip as possible, while not touching the neighbouring components. It will store as much heat as possible while also transferring it as quickly as possible to the components. So we need to know the dimensions of what you are likely to solder.

My perf boards have the pad diameter of 2 mm. The Arduino mini pro clone has the pad diameter around 1.4 mm (the pad is almost vanishing there, it's just a thin ring around the hole). The GY-213V-SI7021 temp/humidity sensors have about 2 mm pad diameter. On the other hand, there are also PCBs with 1.27 mm pitch, where the pad diameter is about 1.1 mm.

What tips you should buy depends on what diameter your pads are and whether or not you are willing to have (and switch between) multiple tips. As the first choice, I would go with a 1.6...2 mm tip width. Interestingly, for a popular FX-888D station Hakko doesn't offer a 2 mm chisel tip in the standard version (although there is one in DL version). Around 2 mm, they only [have](https://www.hakko.com/english/products/search_result.php?k=T18-D) 1.6 or 2.4. With 2.4 mm, you will be touching the neighbouring pads. Therefore 1.6 mm is a better option. Note that Ersa sells its Pico and Nano stations with a 1.6 mm chisel tip.

To summarise, 2 mm is probably just fine, while 1.6 mm seems to be an optimal general purpose tip size for beginner electronics DIYers.